# Partial Views MVC3 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, view, partial

I'm using MVC3 razor and in Views folder I have 4 folder:

Shared

- _Layout.cshtml

Folder2

- Index.cshtml
- UploadFile.cshtml

the uploadFile is partial view for folder2s' index.cshtml

Folder3

- Index.cshtml
- _list.cshtml

Folder4

- Index.cshtml
- _CreateFile.cshtml

I'm newbie in MVC3 so I haven't difficult question

How I can use UploadFile.cshtml in _list.cshtml and _createFile.cshtml
I need the same function in other folders which is in UploadFile.cshtml

in UploadFile.cshtml I have

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    function createUploader() {
        var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
            element: document.getElementById('FileUploader'),
            action: 'Chat/FileUpload',
            debug: true
        });
    }
    window.onload = createUploader;     
</script>   
        <div id="FileUploader">     
    <noscript>          
        <p>Please enable JavaScript to use file uploader.</p>
    </noscript>         
</div>
```

and I want to use this uploader in different places not like @Html.Action

like @Html.Partial or somthing like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make some Action in your Controller that returns your `UploadFile` partial view and then call it from anywhere like this

```
@Html.Action("UploadFileAction", "Folder2Controller", params)
```

Also note that it's good practice to start names of partialv iews with underline like `_UploadFile`. It makes your recources more visible to other people.

Otherwise, if you don't want action you can simply call your partial view with `Html.Partial` method. I didn't test it, but it should work

```
@Html.Partial("~/Views/Folder2/UploadFile.cshtml", model)
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the partial in the `/Views/Shared` directory. This will make it accessible from anywhere. You can use it with `Html.Partial`.